# Find closest longest combination

Tags: swift

I have an array with integers [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4] and an integer value 12. I need to return an array of a closest combination of sum of the integer values in the new array.

For example: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4] with value 12. The array that need to returned is [1, 2, 3, 4] because the sum of elements 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 <= 12. This is the longest array and prefered over [1, 7, 4] 1 + 7 + 4 = 12.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A very nice first question! SO is not the right place to post it though. Check out the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out what does belong here. A moderator might move your question to the appropriate  forum. Also you should do at laeast a quick search before posting. Google ["closest combination of sum of the integer"](https://www.google.de/search?q=closest+combination+of+sum+of+the+integer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=a8JJWLDBM4He8ge0k5WgBA)

Comment: @shallowThought Hi, thanks for the nice feedback and thanks for the Google search term. I will look closely at that.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se

Answer (score 0):

I'm not necessary good with algorithms but I would do it like that :

Since your rule is <= 5 you can sort your array : [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 13]
Then, as you don't need integer > 5 you can split your array in 2 parts and take only the first one : [1, 2, 3, 4]
From there you have to add 4 + 3 and match with your value. If it doesn't work do 4 + 2, then 4 + 1. If it's still > 5, loop with 3,2 ; 3,1 ; etc. I did something like this in a Swift way :

```
// Init
let array = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4]
let value = 5
let sortedArray = array.sorted()
let usefulArray = sortedArray.filter() {$0 < value}
var hasCombination = false
var currentIndex = usefulArray.count - 1
var indexForSum = currentIndex - 1

// Process
if currentIndex > 0 {
  hasCombination = true
  while usefulArray[currentIndex] + usefulArray[indexForSum] > value {
  indexForSum -= 1
  if indexForSum < 0 {
    currentIndex -= 1
    indexForSum = currentIndex - 1
  } 
  if currentIndex == 0 {
    hasCombination = false
    break
  }
 }
}

// Result
if hasCombination {
 let combination = [usefulArray[indexForSum], usefulArray[currentIndex]]
} else {
  print("No combination")
}
```

I guess it works, tell me if it doesn't !

Answer (score 0):

this solution works if you dont have repeated numbers in array.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4, -12, 22, 100]
print(array.sorted())
let value = 19

func close(array: [Int], value: Int) -> (Int , Int) {
    let sortedArray = array.sorted()
    var lastNumberBeforValue = sortedArray.first!
    for (index,number) in sortedArray.enumerated() {
        let sub = value - number
        if sub > 0 {
            lastNumberBeforValue = number
        }
        if sortedArray.contains(sub) && sub != number {
            return (sub, number)
        } else if index == sortedArray.count - 1 {
            if sub < 0 {
                let near = close(array: array, value: value - lastNumberBeforValue)
                return (near.0, lastNumberBeforValue)
            }
            let near = close(array: array, value: sub)
            return (near.0, number)
        }
    }
    return (-1,-1)
}

let numbers = close(array: array, value: value)
print(numbers) //prints (4, 13)
```

Comment: Infinite Loop if there is no combination

Comment: @EvaSahz can you give me an array and a value which cause infinite loop?

Comment: replace "-12" by "12" and value = 1

Answer (score 0):

This solution also finds the two Integers in an array which sum is closest to a given value:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 11, 4]
let value = 5

var difference = Int.max
var result = [Int(), Int()]

for firstInt in array {
    for secondInt in array {
        let tempDifference = abs((firstInt + secondInt) - value)
        if tempDifference < difference {
            difference = tempDifference
            result[0] = firstInt
            result[1] = secondInt
        }
    }
}
```

Or a solution that doesn't allow multiple use of the same value:

```
for (firstIndex, firstInt) in array.enumerated() {
    for (secondIndex, secondInt) in array.enumerated() {
        guard firstInt != secondInt else { break }
        let tempDifference = abs((firstInt + secondInt) - value)
        if tempDifference < difference {
            difference = tempDifference
            result[0] = firstInt
            result[1] = secondInt
        }
    }
}
```

You can keep on nesting for-loops and guarding for multiple use of same index, if you want longer result arrays. Finally you can take the valid array with the largest result.count. This is not a vary nice solution though, since it computationally heavy, and requires the array to have a static length.

Comment: Your first solution returns [1,1] when value = 1
The second solution returns [1,2] when value = 1 or 2

Comment: Is that a problem.? Maybe i read the question wrong. You can add more "rules" in guards. So add 'guard firstInt + secondInt <= value else { break }' after the guard in the for-loop

Comment: Well, I guess it is since 1 + 2 != 2